# HelpFile Stops Navigation to App

Tags: c#, winforms, chm

I have a c# winform application that displays an help file when the help button is clicked. The problem is that whenever the help file is shown. if the try to click my main App in the task bar, the HelpFile shows instead.

This is the code that shows the HelpFile

```
    private void frmWelcome_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Help.ShowHelp(this, "HelpFile.chm", "Welcome.htm");
    }
```

Please how do i rectify this. What i want is that the App shows when it is clicked in the taskbar even if the help file is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you passed your main UI form (`this`) into the `ShowHelp()` method as the `Parent` of your help window. Try this

```
private void frmWelcome_HelpButtonClicked(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Help.ShowHelp(new Control(), "HelpFile.chm", "Welcome.htm");
}
```

Comment: @Precious1tj sorry, I didn't test it. Maybe `null` also means the form calling `ShowHelp()` and hence is the same to `this`. I updated my answer, please see.